# How can I print whether the number in the specified index is positive or negative in python using exception handling?

Tags: python

My aim:
Declare a list with 10 integers and ask the user to enter an index.Check whether the number in that index is positive or negative number.If any invalid index is entered, handle the exception and print an error message.(python)
My code:

```
try:
    lst=[1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,9,-10]
    index=input("Enter an index : ")
    def indexcheck(lst, index):
        index=input("Enter an index")
        if index in lst[index]:
            if lst[index]>0:
                print('Positive')
            elif lst[index]<0:
                print('Negative')
            else:
                print('Zero')

except IndexError:
    print("Error found")
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I correct it?
I am a beginner.Please do help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You create a method , but do not use it

Comment: We are also beginner for your code. Please specify the error that you are getting or undesired output you are getting!

Comment: remove the function definition and simply use the code of the function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception handling is ignored with try-except around a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332468/exception-handling-is-ignored-with-try-except-around-a-function-definition)

Comment: Your code has multiple problems: ``indexcheck`` is never called, and thus the body is not executed. The function parameters ``lst, index`` shadow the outer ``lst, index`` variables. The inner ``index`` assignment nullifies both the outer ``index`` as well as the ``index`` parameter. The ``index`` parameter from ``input`` is a ``str``, but an ``int`` is required for indexing. The check ``if index in lst[index]`` checks whether ``index`` is in the *element* ``lst[index]``, e.g. ``5 in -6``, which results in a ``TypeError``. The ``try: except:`` protects defining the function, not calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put the try/except block around the entirety of your code. For instance, you could do the following:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,9,-10]
index=int(input("Enter an index : "))

try:
    if lst[index] > 0:
        print ("Positive")
    else:
        print ("Negative")
except:
    print ("Index our of range")
```

You could wrap this in a function:

```
def check_index(lst, index):
    try:
        if lst[index] > 0:
            print ("Positive")
        else:
            print ("Negative")
    except:
        print ("Index our of range")
```

P.S. I considered 0 as negative, you can change that part yourself :)

Comment: Please don't recommend a catch-all ``except:`` clause.

Comment: As said by @MisterMiyagi, you can specify which exception you want to catch. As he already did that in his original post, I didn't include it here.

Answer (score 2):

There are following issues with your code:

1. You need to convert the `str` object returned by [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to `int`.

   ```
   index = int(input("Enter an index: "))
   ```
2. You also need to call your function `indexcheck`. The python interpreter will only execute it's code when you will call it.
3. `if index in lst[index]:` is not the right way to check for index value being valid for your list.
4. Since you are already trying to check for index validity and your intentional was to use only valid indexes on your list, so you can't get `IndexError` exception. You should instead check for `ValueError` exception (thrown by `int(input(...))` if `str` can't be converted to an `int`).

I have tired to modify your code as less as possible. My intention is to show the right way of doing things with your code. Try this:

```
try:
    lst = [1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,9,-10]
    def indexcheck(lst):
        index = int(input("Enter an index: "))
        if 0 > index >= len(lst):
            print("Index: %d not found" % (index))
            return
        if lst[index] > 0:
            print('Positive')
        elif lst[index] < 0:
            print('Negative')
        else:
            print('Zero')
    indexcheck(lst)

except ValueError:
    print("Value entered can't be converted to an int")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
def indexcheck(lst, index):
    if 0 <= index < len(lst):
        if lst[index] > 0:
            return 'Positive'
        elif lst[index]<0:
            return 'Negative'
        else:
            return 'Zero'
    else:
        raise Exception("Index out of range")


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, -7, -8, 9, -10]
index = int(input("Enter an index : "))
indexcheck(lst, index)
```

Comment: Because the user asked with exception handling. Do not know why downvoted. Completely disagree. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: You are right, my bad for not having read completely. Already fixed it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are defining a function but not calling it.
2. `input("Enter an index : ")` returns a string. You need to convert that into an `int` as all the `lst` indices are integers.

The working code is given below:

```
def fun():
    try:
        lst=[1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,9,-10]
        index=int(input("Enter an index : "))
        def indexcheck(lst, index):
            if lst[index]>0:
                print('Positive')
            elif lst[index]<0:
                print('Negative')
            else:
                print('Zero')

        indexcheck(lst, index)

    except IndexError:
        print("Error found")

fun()
```