# Trying to raise a custom exception within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass


class Circle:
    try:
        def __init__(self, radius):
            if isinstance(radius, int):
                pass
            else:
                raise RadiusInputError
            self.radius = radius
    except RadiusInputError:
        print('Radius is not a number')


c1 = Circle('hello')
```

the code should execute the except block when a non integer value is passed as radius but it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Pycharm Projects/HelloWorld/HandsOn10.py", line 17, in <module>
    c1 = Circle('hello')
  File "D:/Pycharm Projects/HelloWorld/HandsOn10.py", line 11, in __init__
    raise RadiusInputError
__main__.RadiusInputError
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception handling is ignored with try-except around a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332468/exception-handling-is-ignored-with-try-except-around-a-function-definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrapped your `__init__()` function declaration inside the `try/except` block but function declaration can't raise an exception.

You should consider one of the following:

1. wrap the content of the `__init__` func in `try/except`:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        try:
            if isinstance(radius, int):
                pass
            else:
                raise RadiusInputError
            self.radius = radius
        except RadiusInputError:
            print('Radius is not a number')
```

2. wrap the initialisation of the object:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        if isinstance(radius, int):
            pass
        else:
            raise RadiusInputError
        self.radius = radius


try:
    c1 = Circle('hello')
except RadiusInputError:
    print('Radius is not a number')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `try/except` block will be executed exactly once - *at the definition of this class*:

```
class Circle:
    try:
        # try to define this method
        def __init__(self, radius):
            if isinstance(radius, int):
                pass
            else:
                raise RadiusInputError
            self.radius = radius
        # if we got here, the method has been defined successfully!
    except RadiusInputError:
        # if we got here, an exception occurred WHILE DEFINING THE METHOD
        print('Radius is not a number')
```

This code doesn't affect the *calls* to `Circle.__init__` in the slightest.

You can see how it works here:

```
>>> class Test:
...  print("before definition")
...  def __init__(self):
...    print("inside __self__")
...  print("after definition - bye!")
... 
before definition
after definition - bye!
>>> Test()
inside __self__
<__main__.Test object at 0x103541438>
>>>
```

You have to process exceptions at the call site:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        if not isinstance(radius, int):
            raise RadiusInputError("Wrong radius!")
        self.radius = radius

try:
    c1 = Circle('hello')
except RadiusInputError as err:
    print(f"Oops, something went wring: {err}"!)
```